# Image followed by an inline div with two block divs inside

Tags: css

I've read quite a few links about the problem but i can't grasp why the following fiddle is the way it is. I maybe missed some point, so my apologies in advance. It hasn't really been my day.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Chamster/v7eUN/2/) you have this line break which i claim shouldn't be there, because both the external divs are styled "display: inline". Why are in the inner divs (set to style "display: block") affecting the line break?!

The way i see it, the external divs should be on one line and the line break should occur **inside** the second div. Also, the first div shouldn't be necessary, since img is inline by default.

Any explanation?

Comment: style="inline" is not valid. If you correct it to style="display:inline", there is no line break.

Comment: Downvoter: care to comment?! And where does it say *style="inline"*?!

Comment: It says that on the very first line. It's pointed out in every response below, but now 8 months later you're asking where it is? Btw, I wasn't the downvoter :)

Comment: @bhamlin Oh, first line in the fiddle? Right... This is embarrassing... I simply didn't got that. And, apparently, I wasn't very invested in this particular question. I **do deserve** to be downvoted, haha. Two more down hits and I'll have me a new badge, Vote me down, I dare you!   :)

Comment: @bhamlin No, Now I remember. This was one of my very first posts on SO. I was totally confused and was so happy I resolved my problem that I forgot (didn't know) to get back to the question. I should be awarded a kick in the nuts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `<div style="display: inline">` for the 1st div and it will work - http://jsfiddle.net/v7eUN/3/

It was `<div style="inline">` - just a typo after a hard day, I guess?

Comment: Yes, trouble sleeping. It has been like this the whole day. Nevertheless, even after correcting the style, i get behavior that i wouldn't expect. http://jsfiddle.net/Chamster/v7eUN/7/ Why are the text lines not on top of each other **and** to the right of the image? The both external divs **are** inline...

Comment: That's the normal behavior - an inline element has no line break before or after it, and it tolerates HTML elements next to it. So if you put 3 inline elements next to each other - they will be *in line*

Comment: Yes. Correct. But why do i get a line break in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/Chamster/v7eUN/7/)? The external divs **are** indeed inline, so they should be after each other **but** the internal text divs are block, and should be on top of each other **without** getting below the image. What do i miss? And how can i resolve it?

Comment: You want this - http://jsfiddle.net/v7eUN/10/ ?

Comment: Yes. Yes i do! Muchos thankos! While it works i can't help wondering why i do need "inline-block" there? We don't need any of the vertical alignment, not height properties in this case, so why didn't it work my way?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/v7eUN/11/ - you see what happens if you include `block` elements in `inline` ones(which is not valid BTW).. the `inline ` element will behave like an inline one, and the `block`-s will behave as blocks and take up 100% of the parent width. I mean the closest **block** parent, because they ignore the `inline` one

Comment: Ah, makes perfect sense. I knew that all along. Just wanted to check if you did...   :) **Really great explanation!**

Answer (score 0):

You have mistyped the `style` for the main `div`, you need to use `style="display: inline"` not `style="inline"`.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/v7eUN/4/

Comment: Yes, i've been pointed that out to. But i have a question which is valid **after** the correction. Why do the text lines get **below** the image, instead of to the right? The external divs **are** inline... http://jsfiddle.net/Chamster/v7eUN/7/

Comment: @KonradViltersten - Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/v7eUN/8/